# Compress a dictionary with shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ubuntu, compression

I want to compress a dictionary with this format: 2011.16.03_root_backup.tar.gz (date followed by username). But my shell script code doesn't working and some missing code. May you help me please?

```
#!/bin/sh
date=$(date +"%y-%d-%m")
user=$(whoami)
target=(i want to get this as an argument)
tar -cvf ./$date_$user_backup.tar.gz $target
```

Comment: In what way does your script not work? This is useful information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this line for your tar command:

```
tar -czvf ./${date}_${user}_backup.tar.gz ${target}
```

Problem was that _ after $date or $user is not considered a word separator by shell that's why ${var} form is needed here.

Comment: Are you sure that it will gzip it without `z` option?

Comment: @khachik: Thanks, thats a good catch, it was a typo. I added z option in tar command above.

Comment: An underscore is not considered a word separator because it's a valid character in a variable name.